# MYSQL -Trigger to insert a column value after insert of another value in same row

Tags: mysql

I have table called qbanks with columns cc varchar(25) and cid varchar(25)
I want to insert  cid column when cc value is inserted.I want to use a trigger.
For example ,if cc is 'cm389' then the trigger must insert 'cm38901',when cc is 'cm581' then trigger must insert cid as 'cm58101'.But when again cc is inserted 'cm581' then trigger must insert cid as 'cm58102' i.e use of auto increment.plz help. I have tried after update trigger.plzz plzz help.

Comment: Ok. that's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list and expect someone else to do your job for you.

Comment: Better to handle this kind of logics at application business layer instead of handling at db level